# Puppet & Hiera hierarchy & class names

Tags: inheritance, puppet, hiera

The 'calling_class' lookup variable in Hiera is giving me headaches.

Given a hiera config like so:

```
---
:backends: yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: 
:hierarchy:
  - "node/%{::clientcert}"
  - "profile/%{calling_class}"
  - "roles/%{calling_class}"
  - common
:logger: console
```

And a role.pp in Puppet with the following:

```
class role::base {
  notify { "output scope 1":
    message => inline_template("scope='<%= scope.source.name %>'"),
  }
  $profiles = hiera_array('role::profiles', [])
  notify { "Including profiles: ${profiles}": }
  # include $profiles
}

class role::app inherits role::base{
  notify { "output scope 2":
    message => inline_template("scope='<%= scope.source.name %>'"),
  }
  $profiles = hiera_array('role::profiles', [])
  notify { "Including profiles: ${profiles}": }
}
```

And a `roles/role::app.yaml` with the following:

```
---
role::profiles:
  - webserver
  - application
```

I'd expect to see something like this:

```
Notice: Including profiles: webapp
Notice: scope='role::app'
Notice: Including profiles: webapp
Notice: scope='role::app'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.11 seconds
```

But this is what I'm getting:

```
Notice: Including profiles: 
Notice: scope='role::base'
Notice: Including profiles: webapp
Notice: scope='role::app'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.11 seconds
```

It seems that when a class is inherited ( or included, happens the same either way ) that 'calling_class' in Hiera is set to the inherited class, not the class doing the inheriting. Am I missing something, or is this the way that Hiera is supposed to work? I thought that inheriting a class would set the `scope.source.name` to the child class, not the parent.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't try and rely on `$calling_class` for *anything* that is not mere eye-candy/fluff.

Comment: @FelixFrank I was hoping to use it to make it easier to split Hiera's data out into a hiearchy based on the class I'm calling it from.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this solution. Only disadvantage is that the max number of roles is hardcoded. This will be better with hiera 3 until then try this:

/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml

```
 ---
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: /etc/puppet/hieradata
:hierarchy:
  - 'nodes/%{::clientcert}'
  - 'roles/%{::role_4}'
  - 'roles/%{::role_3}'
  - 'roles/%{::role_2}'
  - 'roles/%{::role_1}'
  - common
```

/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp

```
# Get roles
$roles = hiera_array('roles', [])

# Declare Roles in vars (not needed in puppet 4)
$role_1 = $roles[0]
$role_2 = $roles[1]
$role_3 = $roles[2]
$role_4 = $roles[3]

# Include Classes
hiera_include('classes')
```

/etc/puppet/hieradata/roles/webserver.yaml

```
---
classes:
  - nginx

# put nginx config here
```

/etc/puppet/hieradata/nodes/your_node_name.yaml

```
---
roles:
 - webserver

classes:
# put node specific stuff here
```